# Enviar JsonObject en http post

Tags: java, http

Estoy intentando enviar el value de un JSonObject en una solicitud post con autorización de mi token pero no logro enviar el json no encuentro como con http client.

```
 JsonObject value = (JsonObject) Json.createObjectBuilder() // en value esta el json que necesito enviar 


 URL object = new URL("https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "MYTOKEN");
// Como enviar el value json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguendo tu ejemplo, para agregar un objeto en la petición debes de tener `con.setDoOutput(true);` y luego obtener el `OutputStream` de la conexión.

```
 JsonObject value = (JsonObject) Json.createObjectBuilder() 

 URL object = new URL("https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments");
            
 HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
 con.setDoOutput(true);
 con.setDoInput(true);
 con.setRequestMethod("POST");
 con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
 con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
 con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "MYTOKEN");

 // Obtenemos el OutputStream para agregar el json de la petición.
 try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
    byte[] input = value.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
    os.write(input, 0, input.length);
 }

 // Obtener la respuesta
 try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
     StringBuilder respuesta = new StringBuilder();
     String acumuladorRespuesta = null;
     while ((acumuladorRespuesta = br.readLine()) != null) {
         respuesta.append(acumuladorRespuesta.trim());
     }
     System.out.println(respuesta.toString());
 }
```